# How to filter adult words

Tags: user-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

I am developing a web application, and do not want people to publish adult (pornographic) content.

So is there a service or a list of words which are porn related?

Or is there another way to filter adult content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=censor+censorship+obscenity

Comment: This could have unintended consequences, such as the blocking of sexual health terms, such as "breast cancer" "safe sex" "condom", i also see many blogs that get around this by saying "p0rn" or [s]ex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done, [Disney failed](http://habitatchronicles.com/2007/03/the-untold-history-of-toontowns-speedchat-or-blockchattm-from-disney-finally-arrives/).
If you restrict the words that can be used you'll just see things like this:

> I want to stick my long-necked Giraffe up your fluffy white bunny

What you need is a good way for users to flag inappropriate content and a mechanism to deal with it swiftly. One way is to automatically hide/remove content if it's been flagged more than `X` times.

Comment: I recommend WebPurify for their API profanity filter. They're constantly improving and upgrading their algorithms, so it just gets better over time: http://www.webpurify.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware of the [medireview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medireview) problem when filtering ;-) It is quite easy to make a false positive when using simple text filtering algorithms. Maybe it's even worth considering [Bayesian statistical classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) approach used in spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=consbreastution) and [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=clbuttic). Read: it cannot be done.