# Implementation of PHP profanity filter

Tags: php, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

I have an iPhone app that passes a string through a URL to my php script, which then inserts to my database. I'd like to write some php code that reads $body for any pre-defined profanity.

Right now, I only have the following code, but it only looks for exact matches, not if $body contains, then.. type of a sequence. Also, I need it to replace the swear with a blank " ", removing the word all together.

```
if($body == "swear word") 
    return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$swears = array("shoot", "darn", "heck");

foreach ($swears as $bad_word)
    $body = str_replace($bad_word, " ", $body);
```

This will work as a quick-and-dirty solution, although it does have the [Scunthorpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) (e.g. "heckler" will get transformed to "ler" if "heck" is on your profanity list).

Comment: This is a [clbuttic mistake](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) ;)

Comment: True enough. Edited in something to that effect.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the Scunthorpe Problem. How can you make the array case insensitive?

Comment: Use `str_ireplace` instead of `str_replace` if you want to match case-insensitively.