# php -> delete items from array which contain words from a blacklist

Tags: php, arrays

I have got an array with several twitter tweets and want to delete all tweets in this array which contain one of the following words blacklist|blackwords|somemore

who could help me with this case?

Comment: Could you display some of the code you have tested or are trying to use? how about posting the array format with the tweets? Could be useful

Comment: how is the blacklist|blackwords|somemore stored? DB, array, files...

Comment: Without knowing the format of your array and the format of your blacklist, this question is rather hard to answer.

Comment: *(related)* [How do you implement a good profanity filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
<?php
$banned_words = 'blacklist|blackwords|somemore';
$tweets = array( 'A normal tweet', 'This tweet uses blackwords' );
$blacklist = explode( '|', $banned_words );

//  Check each tweet
foreach ( $tweets as $key => $text )
{
    //  Search the tweet for each banned word
    foreach ( $blacklist as $badword )
    {
        if ( stristr( $text, $badword ) )
        {
            //  Remove the offending tweet from the array
            unset( $tweets[$key] );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of checking against a string for blacklisted words - makes the code awkward to maintain, and array is easier to manage.

Comment: @electblake: Sure, but as others point out, we have no idea what the source of the blacklist is, so I just wrote something simple, to clearly show where data was coming from and how it was analysed. Hence why I *didn't* use array_filter ;)

Comment: yeah - good point :) I tend to assume the simplest situation or at least ideal circumstances - which probably isn't a good thing!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
$badwords = ... // initialize badwords array here
function filter($text)
{
    global $badwords;
    foreach ($badwords as $word) {
        return strpos($text, $word) === false;
    }
}

$result = array_filter($tweetsArray, "filter");
```

Comment: the word "global" always scares me a bit, but I definitely like using `array_filter()`

Answer (score 4):

use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php)

Check this sample

```
$tweets = array();

function safe($tweet) {
    $badwords = array('foo', 'bar');

    foreach ($badwords as $word) {
        if (strpos($tweet, $word) !== false) {
            // Baaaad
            return false;
        }
    }
    // OK
    return true;
}

$safe_tweets = array_filter($tweets, 'safe'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a lot of ways, so without more information, I can give this really starting code:

```
$a = Array("  fafsblacklist hello hello", "white goodbye", "howdy?!!");
$clean = Array();
$blacklist = '/(blacklist|blackwords|somemore)/';

foreach($a as $i) {
  if(!preg_match($blacklist, $i)) {
    $clean[] = $i;
  }
}

var_dump($clean);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

> `preg_grep($array,"/blacklist|blackwords|somemore/",PREG_GREP_INVERT)`

But i warn you that this may be inneficient and you must take care of punctuation characters in the blacklist.