# any open-source/free .NET profanity filter for website?

Tags: c#, profanity

Are you aware of any open-source/free .NET profanity filter (ASP.NET MVC to be precise)? I searched google but I couldn't come up with any. I would like to avoid implementing it entirely on my own, if possible. It is so easy to make mistake or overlook something.

Comment: See here for some discussion around this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter

Comment: I did take a look at that discussion.  Nothing for .NET (at least free/open source)

Comment: Why would you ever need such a thing?

Comment: It is just one of those things you need to have...

Comment: @CodeInChaos I need one as the client i am work for would prefer not to have swear words on their site as it is based at children.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What a ******* good question.

(I would have added this as a comment, but I'm a ****)

**Update**

Ok, here is something that might be a bit more useful:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/07/03/simple-net-profanity-filter.aspx

The above describes a simple swear filter from a list of words using regular expressions.

You could download a list of swear words from here - http://www.noswearing.com/

Comment: I did stumble upon that link, but it leaves implementation in my hand and by reading the comments, it seemed more on the naive side. I could be wrong. I will give that a try if nothing open-source is available.

Comment: thanks, i finaly found what i was looking for between the closed question or downvoted questions -_-..

Answer (score 0):

albeit not .net specific, here's an open source list of profane words in multiple languages you can use https://github.com/uvasoftware/yara-language-nsfw