# Add minimum characters to 'bad word' regex?

Tags: php, regex

I made a `regex` that captures 'bad words' and substitutes with *** so I can return to user in a form if bad words found, a simplified version can be found here:

```
https://regex101.com/r/alEb61/3

(?i)\b(Bitch)\b
```

I'd like to also require min 25 characters in the same regex instead of having to run two separate passes on it (e.g. 1) Bad Words 2) Enough Chars?) is that possible? I basically need to add to above some "less than 25 characters" pipe.

Comment: Are you saying that each match should be a minimum of 25 characters long(For example Bitch would fail)? Or that the complete string should be 25 characters long?

Comment: @AlexCollins I'm saying that in addition to there not being any bad word matches the total length of the input string should exceed 25 characters. I suppose `^.{0,15}$` catches that.

Answer (score 1):

Regex minimum is {min,max} so {1,15} Min of 1 character, max of 15.

I'd do a list of "bad words" then say at least 1 must exist

As far as regex limit goes  `/^[word]{1,15}$/`  - Must be 1 -> 15 "word" found

Check this post out [Profanity Filter using a Regular Expression (list of 100 words)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319136/profanity-filter-using-a-regular-expression-list-of-100-words)

Comment: Thanks but in fact the 15 chars is minimum for the entire string. I added `^.{0,15}$` as a condition (of course the issue is i can't have a 'one size fits all alert' for the user) which works well. The link is great yet I'm not looking for a perfect real-time bad-word blocker just a way to discourage both profanity and nonesense inputs.

Comment: It was simply shown as an example. You can make a list of "bad" words, and you can check if any of them are present in a string or 1 or more exist

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to replace any bad word on your list and the whole string shorter than 25 chars, use

```
 $s = preg_replace('~^.{0,24}$|\b(?:badWord1|badWordN)\b~i', 'CENSURED', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i4Etle/1).

**Details**

- `^.{0,24}$` - first alternative
- `|` - or
- `\b(?:badWord1|badWordN)\b`- the second alternative:

  - `\b` - leading word boundary
  - `(?:` - start of an alternation non-capturing group
  - `badWord1` - bad word #1
  - `|` - or
  - `badWordN`  - bad word N
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

If you plan to match any string longer than 24 chars and not having bad words in it, use

```
'/^(?!.*\bbadword\b).{25,}$/s'
```

It will match a string that has at least 25 chars and does not contain `badword` as a whole word.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cvIbdf/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\bbadword\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if after any 0+ chars there is a whole word `badword`
- `.{25,}` - any 25 or more chars'
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: In the end I did something slightly different as my goal was to capture which words were wrong if any and substitute OR if there were not enough characters. In other words I was trying to match IF a bad word OR if less than X Chars. See my own answer

Comment: @MarkH Do you mean you are using something like `preg_replace('~^.{0,15}$|\b(?:badWord1|badWordN)\b~', 'CENSURED', $s)`? And where is your answer?

Comment: My answer is below and I simply pulled the code regex101 made me and yes appears to be using `preg_replace` (I provided that code to my coders to implement in the form).

Comment: @MarkH: But your solution only finds bad words at the start of the string. See my solution in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created my own version as what I wanted to do was only capture matches IF there was a "bad word" or if there were less than X.

`^(?i)(?P<Words>\bBadWord1|BadWordN\b)|(?P<Characters>^.{0,25}$)$`

which can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/c9ocrk/1/)

This served my purpose as

- if there are no bad words and > 25 chars it returns no matches and the substitution is not even needed (but can be used)
- If there are bad words it indicates that and also substitutes them with * so I can replace the user input text with an alert to replace 'Bad Words' and I know this is the error since the Capture Group is named `Words`
- If there are no bad words but not enough characters it will return the Capture Group as `Characters` so I can return that alert instead.