# word profanity match in php

Tags: php, profanity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

i need to build a script that remove bad words from someone post or username or anythong else they submit to my site.

i have a small script that already remove them but it also cut good words like: `a**`, `f**k`, etc...

now my problem is i have a script that already remove bad words (from my list) but it also remove good one

```
a** and glass
```

i do:

```
str_replace('a**', '***', $message);
```

i want to make sure i wont strip good words or first name for example, what is the best solution?

thanks

Comment: This is a clbuttic mistake.

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter).

Comment: If you have too, I'd find a class that's already available. In the answer to the question Raisen links to, it looks like there are a couple referenced.

Comment: To solve your particular issue, just replace `' ass '` instead of `ass`. But people will still be able to write `a s s` if they want to. Also, note that *ass* can refer to a mammal, a collection of all associated primes or the American Sociological Society.

Comment: so ignore the fact that its a bad idea, and do it anyway !

Comment: @Dennis - What about `-ass-`, `.ass.`, `You are such an ass.`? If it's looking for spaces, you're `sc***ed`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The question was about removing false positives. Just in case it did not show in my first comment: I think that a profanity filter is a horrible feature.

Comment: @Dennis - Just reinforcing why it's tilting at windmills. `:D`

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Nevermind. I misunderstood the *@Dennis* part...