# nltk pos tag expletives

Tags: python, tags, nltk, part-of-speech

is there a way to show which words are **filler words** in a given text using **NLTK**?
if not does anyone know where I can get a *wordlist* with english fill words?
thank you

**SOLVED:** from nltk.corpus import stopwords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLTK doesn't provide such a list by itself, though many are available elsewhere on the Web.

There exist quite a number of sources: Web searchs for wordlists with "**profanity**" *"badwords.txt"* or *blacklists.txt* will yield many sources.

- [noswearing.com](http://www.noswearing.com/dictionary) is one place to start.
- Sites like Netnanny and several others use "**censor lists**" ([this thread has a link](http://www.phorum.org/phorum5/read.php?63,127769)). Download one and start from there.

In our company's case, we ended up creating our own list and adding to it as needed. Depending on your audience, the list has to be tweaked and adjusted.

Finally, Even though this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter) is closed (and about php) I have found the references and the discussion very useful.

**UPDATE:** What you want is a list of **STOP WORDS**.

1. Try: http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html
2. [MIT also maintains a list](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop) of stop words.

Hope that helps.

Comment: apparently the word expletive also stands for badwords, what I meant was not badwords but **filler words**, is there a way where to obtain such a list? or does NLTK provide it?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your clarification