# PHP swear word filter

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that replaces the bad words from the comments with random new ones from a list.

I now have 2 arrays: one containing the bad words and another containing the good words.

```
$bad = array("bad", "words", "here");
$good = array("good", "words", "here");
```

Since I'm a beginner, I got stuck at some point.

In order to replace the bad words, I've been using `$newstring = str_replace($bad, $good, $string);`.

My first problem is that I want to turn off the case sensivity, so I won't put the words like this `"bad", "Bad", "BAD", "bAd", "BAd", etc` but I need the new word to keep the format of the original word, for example if I write "Bad", it would be replaced with "Words", but if I type "bad", it would be replaced with "words", etc.

My first tought was to use `str_ireplace`, but it forgets if the original word had a capital letter.

The second problem is that I don't know how to deal with the users that type like this: "b a d", "w o r d s", etc. I need an idea.

In order to make it select a random word, I think I can use `$new = $good[rand(0, count($good)-1)];` then `$newstring = str_replace($bad, $new, $string);`. If you have a better idea, I'm here to listen.

The general look of my script:

```
function noswear($string)
{
    if ($string)
    {       
        $bad = array("bad", "words");
        $good = array("good", "words"); 
        $newstring = str_replace($bad, $good, $string);     
        return $newstring;
}

echo noswear("I see bad words coming!");
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I see mbuttive problems in your future.

Comment: and then users will come with `wboardd (take every second character… damn filters!)`

Comment: The only way to prevent offensive user input is to prevent all user input.

Comment: Don't forget the dick is short for richard conundrum...

Comment: its hard...check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter) SO post. to reiterate the other comments, a quick line from the post..."I want to stick my long-necked Giraffe up your fluffy white bunny.". humans are creative, you block one thing and we'll find another way.

Comment: This would be a clbuttic mistake indeed.

Comment: Yes, but it can also be "I want you to pet my dog, you nice guy!"

Comment: If you implement a word filter, I will find you and buttbuttinate you in your sleep!

Answer (score 11):

## Precursor

There are (as has been pointed out in the comments numerous times) gaping holes for you - and/or your code - to fall into through implementing such a feature, to name but a few:

1. People will add characters to *fool* the filter
2. People will become *creative* (e.g. innuendo)
3. People will use passive aggression and sarcasm
4. People will use sentences/phrases not just words

You'd do better to implement a moderation/flagging system where people can flag offensive comments which can then be edited/removed by mods, users, etc.

On that understanding, let us proceed...

## Solution

Given that you:

1. Have a forbidden word list `$bad_words`
2. Have a replacement word list `$good_words`
3. Want to replace bad words *regardless of case*
4. Want to replace bad words with *random* good words
5. Have a correctly escaped *bad word* list: see http://php.net/preg_quote

You can very easily use `PHP`s `preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$input_string = 'This Could be interesting but should it be? Perhaps this \'would\' work; or couldn\'t it?';

$bad_words  = array('could', 'would', 'should');
$good_words = array('might', 'will');

function replace_words($matches){
    global $good_words;
    return $matches[1].$good_words[rand(0, count($good_words)-1)].$matches[3];
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/(^|\b|\s)('.implode('|', $bad_words).')(\b|\s|$)/i', 'replace_words', $input_string);
```

Okay, so what the `preg_replace_callback` does is it compiles a regex pattern consisting of all of the *bad words*. Matches will then be in the format:

```
/(START OR WORD_BOUNDARY OR WHITE_SPACE)(BAD_WORD)(WORD_BOUNDARY OR WHITE_SPACE OR END)/i
```

The `i` modifier makes it case insensitive so both `bad` and `Bad` would match.

The function `replace_words` then takes the matched word and it's boundaries (either blank or a white space character) and replaces it with the boundaries and a random *good word*.

```
global $good_words; <-- Makes the $good_words variable accessible from within the function
$matches[1] <-- The word boundary before the matched word
$matches[3] <-- The word boundary after  the matched word
$good_words[rand(0, count($good_words)-1] <-- Selects a random good word from $good_words
```

#### Anonymous function

You could rewrite the above as a one liner using an anonymous function in the `preg_replace_callback`

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|\b|\s)('.implode('|', $bad_words).')(\b|\s|$)/i',
        function ($matches) use ($good_words){
            return $matches[1].$good_words[rand(0, count($good_words)-1)].$matches[3];
        },
        $input_string
    );
```

#### Function wrapper

If you're going to use it multiple times you may also write it as a self-contained function, although in this case you're most likely going to want to feed the good/bad words in to the function when calling it (or hard code them in there permanently) but that depends on how you derive them...

```
function clean_string($input_string, $bad_words, $good_words){
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|\b|\s)('.implode('|', $bad_words).')(\b|\s|$)/i',
        function ($matches) use ($good_words){
            return $matches[1].$good_words[rand(0, count($good_words)-1)].$matches[3];
        },
        $input_string
    );
}

echo clean_string($input_string, $bad_words, $good_words);
```

#### Output

Running the above functions consecutively with the input and word lists shown in the first example:

```
This will be interesting but might it be? Perhaps this 'will' work; or couldn't it?
This might be interesting but might it be? Perhaps this 'might' work; or couldn't it?
This might be interesting but will it be? Perhaps this 'will' work; or couldn't it?
```

Of course the *replacement words* are chosen randomly so if I refreshed the page I'd get something else... But this shows what does/doesn't get replaced.

### N.B.

#### Escaping `$bad_words`

```
foreach($bad_words as $key=>$word){
    $bad_words[$key] = preg_quote($word);
}
```

#### Word boundaries `\b`

In this code I've used `\b`, `\s`, and `^` or `$` as word boundaries there is a good reason for this. While `white space`, `start of string`, and `end of string` are all considered word boundaries `\b` will not match in all cases, for example:

```
\b\$h1t\b <---Will not match
```

This is because `\b` matches against non-word characters (i.e. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`) and characters like `$` don't count as *word* characters.

#### Misc

Depending on the size of your word list there are a couple of potential hiccups. From a system design perspective it's generally bad form to have *huge* regexes for a couple of reasons:

1. It can be difficult to maintain
2. It's difficult to read/understand what it does
3. It's difficult to find errors
4. It can be memory *intensive* if the list is too large

Given that the regex pattern is compiled by `PHP` the first reason is negated. The second should be negated as well; if you're word list is *large* with a dozen permutations of each *bad word* then I suggest you **stop** and rethink your approach (read: use a flagging/moderation system).

To clarify, I don't see a problem have a *small word list* to filter out specific expletives as it serves a purpose: to stop users from having an outburst at one another; the problem comes when you try to filter out **too much** including permutations. Stick to filtering common swear words and if that doesn't work then - *for the last time* - implement a flagging/moderation system.

Comment: I would also advise heavily against globals: you don't need it for your closure (`function($matches) use($bad_words,$good_words){}` works fine), and one is far better of with predictable, reliable and testable code if the function gets those lists as _arguments_.

Comment: I must be reading this _out of context_ "I would also"; Is there a previous comment which I've missed??

Comment: As for the use of `global`: while I agree that you could use `use` with the anonymous function you couldn't use it in the way that you're suggesting for a couple of reasons one being purely because `$bad_words` is not passed in. However, `function ($matches) use($good_words){}` _could_ be used in the **Anonymous Function** example above. But in the function `clean_string` to do the same you would have to reference `$good_words` in the parent/named function (as `use` only takes from the parent).

Comment: In this case it's simpler and more readable to simply use the `global` keyword. Otherwise you would have to pass in word list arguments every time you called the function (e.g. `clean_string($input_string, $bad_words, $good_words)`) which might not be a huge pain but certainly isn't necessary, having said that I did mention that feeding the word lists as arguments is something that (would be preferred) if it was to be turned into a function.

Comment: I also suggested that the OP may instead initialise them in the function (as I assume the lists will come from files or database tables) in which case neither `global` nor `use` would be used.

Comment: yes, the _also_ was about a deleted portion where I was dead-wrong (the `\b` part). But: using globals, _especially_ when talking to developing coders (which I'm sure you know are all to copy/paste happy), _even as an example_ is IMHO not a good idea. Making them arguments, feeding them to a closure, making it a tiny class with properties and a method, even if we insist on wanting a global state static variables & a static method in a class, all equally easy to incorporate in the examples. And it prevents the allure of just using it _as is_, with the globals.

Comment: @Wrikken I concede your point regarding copy/paste. In all fairness, I copy/pasted the original `replace_words` function into the later two examples and just didn't update it... Anyway, given that it was a 10 second fix (essentially copy/pasting a few lines in different places) I have updated the code to _not use_ the `global` key word and instead require the word lists to be passed in as arguments.

Comment: Excellent, my thanks, and possibly the thanks of any future colleagues of new coders reading it ;)

Answer (score 5):

I came up to this method and it's working fine. Returning *true*, in case there is an entry of bad words in the entry.

*Example:*

```
function badWordsFilter($inputWord) {
  $badWords = Array("bad","words","here");
  for($i=0;$i<count($badWords);$i++) {
     if($badWords[$i] == strtolower($inputWord))
        return true;
     }
  return false;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
if (badWordsFilter("bad")) {
    echo "Bad word was found";
} else {
    echo "No bad words detected";
}
```

As the word 'bad' is blacklisted it will echo.

#### [Online example 1](http://ideone.com/FIAEQb)

**EDIT 1:**

As offered by *rid* it's also possible to do simple `in_array` check:

```
function badWordsFilter($inputWord) {
  $badWords = Array("bad","words","here");
     if(in_array(strtolower($inputWord), $badWords) ) {
        return true;
     }
  return false;
}
```

#### [Online example 2](http://ideone.com/x2txWw)

**EDIT 2:**

As I promised, I came up to the slightly different idea of replacing bad words with good words, as you mentioned in your question. I hope it will help you a bit but this is the best I can offer at the moment, as I'm totally not sure on what you're trying to do.

*Example:*

1. Let's combine an array with bad and good words into one

```
$wordsTransform = array(
  'shit' => 'ship'
);
```

2. Your imaginary user input

```
$string = "Rolling In The Deep by Adel\n
\n
There's a fire starting in my heart\n
Reaching a fever pitch, and it's bringing me out the dark\n
Finally I can see you crystal clear\n
Go ahead and sell me out and I'll lay your shit bare";
```

3. Replacing bad words with good words

```
$string = strtr($string, $wordsTransform);
```

4. Getting the desired output

> Rolling In The Deep
>
> There's a fire starting in my heart
>   Reaching a fever pitch, and it's bringing me out the dark
>   Finally I can see you crystal clear
>   Go ahead and sell me out and I'll lay your *ship* bare

#### [Online example 3](http://ideone.com/X4RQSJ)

**EDIT 3:**

To follow the correct comment from  *Wrikken*, I have totally forgotten about that `strtr` is case sensitive and that it's better to follow  word-boundary. I have borrowed the following example from 
  [PHP: strtr - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) and modified it slightly.

*Same idea as in my second edit but not register dependent, it checks for word boundaries and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax:*

1. Method:

```
//
// Written by Patrick Rauchfuss
class String
{
    public static function stritr(&$string, $from, $to = NULL)
    {
        if(is_string($from))
            $string = preg_replace("/\b{$from}\b/i", $to, $string);

        else if(is_array($from))
        {
            foreach ($from as $key => $val)
                self::stritr($string, $key, $val);
        }
        return preg_quote($string); // return and add a backslash to special characters
    }
}
```

2. An array with bad and good words

```
$wordsTransform = array(
            'shit' => 'ship'
        );
```

3. Replacement

```
String::stritr($string, $wordsTransform);
```

#### [Online example 4](http://ideone.com/1h0npO)

Comment: try `strtolower` on the `$inputWord` so that it gets around the issue of having 'bAd' getting through... he also wants this to strip bad words from a comment not singular word, so you would have to explode the `$inputWord` into an array and then check each value

Comment: @rid it could be replaced with `in_array()` although this then removes the ease of extending it with regular expression checks for example

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's not what I actually need. My script needs to replace the bad words with another random word from an array, but your script only tells me if there is a bad word or not.

Comment: Understood! What would you like your words to be replaced with? Why not just replace them with `...`?

Comment: I need to replace the bad words with another random words from an array, since I'll have a database with the good and bad words and the arrays may not have equal number of elements, so for each bad word I will take do something like this: `$new = $good[rand(0, count($good)-1)];` to get a random value, then I will replace the bad word with `$new`.

Comment: I will be going to be away soon! I will come back to you in the evening and try to play with your problem in case it wouldn't be solved by then!

Comment: For the love of... at _the very least_ check for word boundaries when you must to this ([there's a reason most comments advise against it](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)). Something like `/\b$word\b/i` in a regex.

Comment: @Wrikken I updated my answer to check for word boundaries! Sorry! You're right! Now it would catch it anyway!

Comment: That is _still_ no **word-boundary**.

Comment: @Wrikken I understood and finally fixed it! Thank you for pointing out useful point!

Comment: And, depending on what the words contain (the often used `$h1t` for instance), use `preg_quote`...