# ignore repeating characters

Tags: regex, replace, character, repeat

I am trying to make a swearing prevention system, so far I have ignored the whitespace (with "\s*") and I've ignored the case("(?i)"). How would I ignore repeated characters ? e.g heeeello.

Comment: I assume you want to end up matching your potential swear word(s) against a "dictionary of swear words", right? And you want to prevent "minor changes" in the swear word from getting past the filter.

Comment: Be sure not to fall into the common trap of censoring assassin or what-have you because of the "ass" in it.

Comment: I'm not using a dictionary no, as the system I'm limited to doesn't allow that, as for assassin, it unfortunately would turn out as a**assin, I most likely won't be blocking ass however.

Comment: you can easily account for the word assassin by checking for spaces before and after

Comment: You might want to check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter) out

Comment: @Brodie Because there are so many differences between different regex engines, it's very helpful if you specify what language / platform you're using when you ask a regex question.

Comment: if it would work wrong, then fix it :). You can use a negative lookahead statement to check for "assin" e.g. `ass+(assin\S*)` will match `ass`, `asses` `assignments` (also a problem), but not `assassin`, `assassinate`, `assassination`, etc

Comment: @A.O. the issue with using that approach is that things like `jackass` and `assmunch` become problematic. It's very hard to do this right.

Comment: Thank you. As to the Regex engine, I myself, don't know. I'm using this program that requires an input and a config file that contains the regex patterns to check. Sorry

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @adsmith again, you're right. But that wasnt my point, my point was that you CAN account for those cases, there's no reason that `assassin` should show up `a**assin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flag that you can turn on to simply ignore any duplicate characters. However, you can use the 'one or more' quantifier (`+`) to match one or more occurrence of any character, character class, or group. For example the pattern `he+l+o` will match all of the following:

- `helo`
- `heelo`
- `hello`
- `heeeello`

Comment: you might also want to use '*', which is the same as above, but accounts for 0 frequency as well, just so the OP knows!

Comment: "sh*it" will censor `sit`. Don't do that.

Comment: @adsmith obviously, i wasn't saying that he SHOULD use '*' i was just saying that there might be cases where it's needed instead of '+'. so it would catch words like btch, fck, mthrfckr and so onnnnnnnn

Comment: Quantifiers should come *after* the character they modify. So if you want to match any sequence of `h e l o` ignoring repetitions or intervening whitespace, the pattern would be `h+\s*e+\s*l+\s*o+`

Comment: This one worked the best and was quite clear. Thanks

Comment: If you worry about repeated characters anywhere in your string, then you need a `+` everywhere in your string...

Comment: @adsmith - I like your example, but AO was talking about `*` in the regex sense of the word, not the `f**k` censoring sense...

Comment: @Floris I was pretty clear about that in an earlier comment. My transmogrification tangent was just that -- tangential. I didn't think that using the "zero or more" regex character related at all with replacing the letter with an asterix

Comment: @adsmith Now that's an interesting idea. I think I'll have to check that out.

Comment: One question I have, I'm trying to censor the work dick, and d i c k is censored, but d i i c k is not censored. Can anyone explain to me how to fix this ? This is my regex pattern: (?i)d+\s*i+\s*c+\s*k+

Comment: @Brodie Well in that case you'd have to use something like `(?i)d+(\s*i)+(\s*c)+(\s*k)+`

Comment: @Brodie it expects a "c" after the `d i `. It will catch `d iiii c k` because you've told it to expect one or more `i`s before the space. Try `(?i)(?:d+\s*)+(?:i+\s*)+(?:c+\s*)+(?:k+\s*)+` which encloses each letter and possible space in a non-capturing group and allows them to repeat. This syntax is subject to interpretation by your regex engine -- it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a general solution to remove repeated characters, you'll want to replace `(.)\1` with `\1` repeatedly as long as it succeeds.

Comment: And thus the banned word "poop" will be replaced with the OK word "pop", and pass the screen...

Comment: Yep. I was thinking of traditional profanity (in English) and couldn't think of a word with consecutive characters. In any event, I think producing word-specific regexes is nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Use + to catch as many repetition of a sequence in () as there are. e+ will catch all the e's in heeeeello.

Check out rubular.com, very simple way to learn, practice and test regex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture a single character then check for any repetition of it with using a backreference to the lately captured group:

```
(.)\1+
```

If string is matched then it has repetition.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/yV6qE5)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is harder than you think. Let's assume that you want to match "no fewer than this number of characters" for each word in your dictionary. Then you would have to create a dictionary of regexes with a `+` after each character…

```
Initial dictionary:
boom
smurf
tree
cannibals
```

Process the dictionary with a text editor:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\+/g' dictionary.txt > regex.txt
```

This puts a `+` between all characters:

```
b+o+o+m+
s+m+u+r+f+
t+r+e+e+
c+a+n+n+i+b+a+l+s+
```

And now you can match your "repeated" words:

```
bom : no match
smuuurf : match
trees   : no match
canibals : no match
cannnibalssss : match
```

You might want to add "word boundaries" - so that `smurfette` doesn't get caught by `smurf`. This would mean adding `\b` before and after each expression ("word boundary").

Note - it's not enough to remove all duplicate letters from both the dictionary, and the words to be matched - otherwise you risk banning "pop" because you had "poop" on your list (and how would you know to stop when "pooop" had reached exactly two characters). This is why I prefer this solution over some of the others that recommend stripping repeats.

Comment: I am impressed that I managed to harvest a down vote for this answer. Can anyone explain?