# bad-good words with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, whitelist, blacklist

I have some list:

```
$bad_words = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
$good_words= ['__aaa', 'bbb==', '#ccc==']
```

By this lists I'd generate these rules:

```
$rules = ['/((?<!__)aaa)/', '/(bbb(?!==))/', '/((?<!#)ccc(?!==))/']
```

Problem: the ccc-rule is not correct (https://regex101.com/r/cC3hY7/1): it must to find strings like `#ccc`, `#ccc--` or `ccc==` and exclude only strings like `#ccc==`

How to fix it?

Comment: Is this used as a censorship filter?

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter) beforehand?

Comment: Agree with Jack. But is this what you wanted? ((?<!__)aaa)|(bbb(?!==))|(#?ccc(?!==))

Comment: @trainoasis Thanx! But I thik the follow solution is better: it is easier to generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `(*SKIP)(*F)` like below.

```
    (?:#ccc==|bbb==|__aaa)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)
#   |<- Strings you don't want ----->|<--strings you want-->
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cC3hY7/2)