# Find similar word for word in the list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make filter bot that can find same characters or same words in message that's listed in block list

```
block = ["damn", "shit"]
```

if message count : daaaaammmmnnnn or sssssshit or da-mn or da.mn. like that catch it and return True

how can I do this.

thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

Comment: @devo means if any list `block` element present in the message string then return True otherwise return False?

Comment: @VivekSable yes and if the message contains same block list but have many characters

Comment: @VivekSable list : damn and message is : daaaaammmmnnnn - return True

Comment: @ceejayoz this url have php lang I'm talking about Python. thnx.

Comment: A better similarity metric is the [*Levenshtein distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: @devodevox The take-away from the duplicate question is "don't bother". PHP vs. Python is irrelevant.

Comment: Bash and regular expressions might be a faster way -->  cat txt |  grep -i d+a+m+n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `flag` value to `True` when message contains any items from the list `block`.

1. Get `block` list and iterate every item from the list by `for` loop.
2. Set value of `flag` to `False` by default means message not contains any block list item.
3. Set value of `flag` to `True` when item from the `block` list in the message.
4. Use `break` statement to stop `for` loop iteration.

e.g.

```
>>> block = ["damn", "shit"]
>>> msg = "test masf to check shit or damn"
>>> flag = False
>>> for i in block:
...   if i in msg:
...      flag = True
...      break
... 
>>> flag
True
>>>
```

---

Updated:

1. Set `block` list words.
2. Create list of list of block list word characters.
3. Remove  punctuation from the input string.
4. split string to words.
5. split word and create sequence list of characters from the word.
6. check sequence list of characters present in block list character list.

code:

```
import string
block = ["damn", "shit"]
block_char_list = [ list(i) for i in block ]

def  getbBlockListFlag(msg):
    #Remove punctuation
    tmp = msg.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    tmp1 = []
    for word in tmp.split():
        j = []
        for k in list(word):
            if k not in j:
                j.append(k)
            elif k != j[-1]:
                j.append(k)

        # word in block list
        if j in block_char_list:
            return True, j

    return False, []



msg = "True test case ? daaaammmmnnnnn.,"
status, block_char = getbBlockListFlag(msg)
if status:  
    print "The word `%s` from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(''.join(block_char), msg)
else:
    print "No word from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(msg)

msg = "True test case ? normal damn.,"
status, bloak_char = getbBlockListFlag(msg)
if status:  
    print "The word `%s` from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(''.join(block_char), msg)
else:
    print "No word from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(msg)

msg = "False test case ? nothing when sequance aaammdddnnn.."
status, bloak_char = getbBlockListFlag(msg)
if status:  
    print "The word `%s` from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(''.join(block_char), msg)
else:
    print "No word from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(msg)


msg = "False test case ? nothing.."
status, bloak_char = getbBlockListFlag(msg)
if status:  
    print "The word `%s` from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(''.join(bloak_char), msg)
else:
    print "No word from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(msg)
msg = "True test case ? Handle  daaaammaaaammnnnnn.,"
status, block_char = getbBlockListFlag(msg)
if status:  
    print "The word `%s` from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(''.join(block_char), msg)
else:
    print "No word from block list is presnt in input '%s'"%(msg)
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 16.py 
The word `damn` from block list is presnt in input 'True test case ? daaaammmmnnnnn.,'
The word `damn` from block list is presnt in input 'True test case ? normal damn.,'
No word from block list is presnt in input 'False test case ? nothing when sequance aaammdddnnn..'
No word from block list is presnt in input 'False test case ? nothing..'
No word from block list is presnt in input 'True test case ? Handle  daaaammaaaammnnnnn.,'
```

Comment: what if msg = "test masf to check shiiiiiiiit or daaaaammmmmmmn"

Comment: `msg` is your input string

Comment: I know that's what I need if I input same word but have many same characters return True

Comment: ok, let me try again. means block list have item `damn` and input string have world like `daaammmnnn` then we have to return `True` otherwise `False` what about when input is `daaann`, return `False`(because `m` is missing) ?? what about when input is `amnd`(sequence is different)  ??

Comment: what about when input is daaann, return False(because m is missing) - yes

Comment: what about when input is amnd(sequence is different) - return False

Comment: daammmaaannnnaaaa is not handled. lookinggg

Comment: @devodevox: Welcome :) handled daammmaaannnnaaaa case also.. check now.. if you have any query then I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

string = "test this string to check for sshh-iitit and dammm.mn"
new_string = string.replace('-','')
final_string = new_string.replace('.','')
words = final_string.split()
for word in words:
    check = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(word))
    if check == "damn" or check == "shit":
        print "true"
```

Comment: How does this handle cases like "daaaaaamn"

Comment: @mac389 change foo to foo = "test this string to check for shhhhhhhhit and daaaaaammmmmmn" , it will print True

Comment: I was suggesting that the proposed solution is not generalizable and could be by using regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)! PHP has this nice function called: leventhstein(). And for Phython is minimum one C  implementation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0