# SQL Filtering and Replacing

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables in SQL that require content filtering, primarily for profanity. I want to allow my application(s) to insert data they want and have the server replace any profanity with asterisks such that I do not need to implement filtering on a variety of platforms.

I know triggers could be used for future, however, I am trying to determine the most efficient way to complete this task.

Here are some details:
There are 2 tables I need to ensure has content filtering as they are public facing: feedback and users. Here are the particular fields:

**Table -> Fields**

Feedback -> Subject, Message
Users -> Firstname, Lastname, Alias

I am relatively new to MySQL and know that having a table of values to replace may be the easiest-to-modify option.

**My question is**:

How would I join 2 tables and replace particular chars with asterisks using key words located in a third table?

I have these queries so far to locate the columns of interest, just not sure how to incorporate the replacement function and the ability to check both at the same time:

`SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.username FROM users u, feedback f, terms t;`

`SELECT f.subject, f.message FROM feedback f;`

Comment: ah an oldie but a goodie: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter

Comment: thanks @xQbert, I saw that, however, I do not have access to the PHP code and want to keep this directly within the SQL Server as directed.. PHP would be so much easier.

Comment: Function call in trigger before update that uses a regular expression  your word list and recursion to replace known offenders you could track offending user and require approvals for their posts over time when exceeding thresholds

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a new column (named `alias` or similar) and storing values with asterisks in there than writing a `SELECT` query and performing find-replace. Following are the advantages:

- Handling this scenario in `trigger` means you will only perform this operation when a record gets inserted or updated, whereas in `SELECT` query, each read will need replacing.
- You can't really use `join` here because (a) each value of feedback and user table needs to be compared with **all** the values of `terms` table and (b) this needs to be performed for all the columns that might contain these words. So, it's more of a use case for `cursor` than `join`.

Comment: I would first want to change out the existing values, then incorporate a trigger, if possible. Would the new column be in the terms table (so the terms table would supply the term and replacement text in two different columns?