# Case Sensitive in Web Browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, case-sensitive, mshtml

I have these codes below where it can identify the bad words (those words are stored in the database) you've entered with the Web Browser Control and turn it into asterisk (*). I have been struggling with case sensitive in which you can enter either lower case or upper case (example: HeLlo)

```
    string query;
    query = @"select Word from ListWords";

    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    DataSet ds;
    DataRow drow;

    ds = DatabaseConnection.Connection1(query);
    int index, total;

    total = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    string current_word;

    for (index = 0; index < total; index++ )
    {
        drow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[index];
        current_word = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();

        words.Add(current_word);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(query);


    Console.WriteLine("array:" + words);
    foreach (String key in words)
    {
        String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";

        int len = key.Length;
        string replace = "";

        for ( index = 0; index < len; index++)
        {
            replace += "*";
        }

        html.Replace(key, replace);
        //count++;
    }


    doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking in this question. Thank you for providing a code example, but to better answer, we will need to know where exactly it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to search the `html` string for words from your filter list, and replace them with some `HTML` coded string plus `*` in place of the 'bad words'.

`Regex` are a great solution for this.

So let's say your have a word list like this:

```
List<string> badWords = new List<string>
{
    "Damn",
    "Hell",
    "Idiot"
};
```

And this is your `HTML`.

```
var html = "You're a damn idIOT!!";
```

OK not a lot of `HTML` in that but bear with me.

Now you iterate through the word list, and we create a `Regex` for each word with ignoring case. Then depending on the length of the word, we create a replacement string. Then call `Regex.Replace()`.

```
foreach (var word in badWords)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var blocked = new string('*', word.Length);
    var replacement = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);'>" + blocked + "</span>";
    html = rgx.Replace(html, replacement);
}
```

---

### Edit

Also, you don't really need to reinvent the wheel. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273516/302248) is a great SO post about profanity filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing the input word with `current_word.ToLower()` before adding them to the list.

MSDN has more info on this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

A simplified approach would be to use the `Regex.Replace` method, which you can pass a flag to ignore case.

Here's an example using a `List<string>` of "bad words", and how it could be used. The downside is that if a word contains a bad word, that part of the word will also be redacted.

```
var badWords = new List<string>
{
    "Bleeping",
    "Bad"
};

var html = "This is my bleeping html file with bad words in it!\n" + 
        "But realize it will replace partial occurrences, too,\n" +
        "for example, now I can't write BADGER!";

Console.WriteLine("Old html:\n" + html + Environment.NewLine);

foreach (var badWord in badWords)
{
    html = Regex.Replace(html, badWord, new string('*', badWord.Length), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

Console.WriteLine("New html:\n" + html);
```

**Output**
[image]