# PHP check if string contains words from array

Tags: php, validation

I would like like to validate changing names by users, and to block setting name values lik adminjohnny or johnnyadmin or johnnyadmin123. I will have array of blocked words and before accept and put name in database i would like to validate it, if it contains any blocked word. How can i do that if blocked word is part of string?

```
$stringToValidate = string;
$blockedWordsArray = array(...);
function validateStringForBlockedWords($blockedWordsArray, $stringToValidate)
```

Comment: Worth a read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem