# How can i detect bad word in any languages

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-dependencies, social-media-like

I am making a social media application and I need to detect bad words if anyone type in message and give him warning.

I did not try to make it, but there are some condition for detecting bad words :

---

> Lets suppose abcd is a bad word

1. If user type abcd then officially it will detected.
2. But if user type abdc then it also need to detected.
3. And if use type abcde then it will detected also.
4. And it need to work in all popular languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)