# How to implement a profanity filter in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I am developing a social web application with RoR. I realized that it's probably a good idea to prevent users from inserting rude or profane language into comments or posts.

Do you know any solution or plug-in that help me prevent something like this?

Answer (score 4):

The correct term you're looking for is a *profanity filter* (edited). Here are some previous discussions on this topic:

- [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)
- ["bad words" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515/bad-words-filter)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259610/profanity-filtering-profanity-dictionaries-scunthorpe-problem-profanity-generat

Comment: TL;DR - It's really hard to make a fool-proof profanity filter. People can always circumvent them by being creative. There are services that specialize in this. Personally, I went with WebPurify and I've been pretty happy: http://www.webpurify.com/