# stristr Case-insensitive search PHP

Tags: php, search, replace, string

Please excuse my noob-iness!

I have a $string, and would like to see if it contains any one or more of a group of words, words link c**t, fu**, sl** ETC. So I was thinking I could do:

```
if(stristr("$input", "dirtyword1"))
{
   $input = str_ireplace("$input", "thisWillReplaceDirtyWord");
}
elseif(stristr("$input", "dirtyWord1"))
{
   $input = str_ireplace("$input", "thisWillReplaceDirtyWord2");
}
```

...ETC. BUT, I don't want to have to keep doing if/elseif/elseif/elseif/elseif...

Can't I just do a switch statement OR have an array, and then simply say something like?:

```
$dirtywords = { "f***", "c***", w****", "bit**" };

if(stristr("$input", "$dirtywords"))
{
   $input = str_ireplace("$input", "thisWillReplaceDirtyWord");
}
```

I'd appreciate any help at all

Thank you

Comment: why are you quoting variables?

Comment: Because that's how I learned to do stristr on the php manual site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php   :)

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515/bad-words-filter

Comment: Basically, any attempt at Bad Word Filtering is futile. I can f u c k over any half-a$$ed filter easily just by letter variation. If that was an achievable task, there would be no more V1agra spam anymore. You'd have better chances with ANALizing the whole text and give it an obscenity rating and if it gets above a threshold, dont show it at all.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm not being paid very much at all for a job that should be paying out of its ass. So, I don't really care. They get what they pay for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dirty = array("fuc...", "pis..", "suc..");
$censored = array("f***", "p***", "s***");

$input= str_ireplace($dirty, $censored , $input);
```

Note, that you don't have to check stristr() to do a str_ireplace()

Comment: I like your choice of words lol. Thanks! :D I will accept in 10mins when it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_ireplace() takes a value from each array and uses them to do search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search  is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search.

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best solution since I don't know too much PHP, but what about a loop ?

```
foreach (array("word1", "word2") as $word)
{
  if(stristr("$input", $word))
  {
     $input = str_ireplace("$input", $word" "thisWillReplaceDirtyWord");
  }
}
```

When you have several objects to test, think "loop" ;-)