# Filtering bad words and all permutations of intentionally misspelled words?

Tags: c#, regex

What's a good way using regular expressions to filter curse words from a block of text?

I don't want to replace the "ass" in classic (a clbuttic mistake), so it needs to be able to earch by word boundary.

Additionally, it would need to catch permutations such as l33tpeak, spaces in the word, etc. it doesn't have to be perfect (the system that this is going into will also have message flagging capabilities) but it should get the majority of cursing that people may use.

PG13 Example: If trying to block the word "moist", then it should be able to match "moist" as well as "m01st", "MOIST", "m0ist" and hopefully "m oist".

Comment: I updated the question with expected results and added more details to make it relevant.

Comment: I wrote it before asking the question, and answered it myself, Q&A style. It was to provide code to anyone who could use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a C# equivalent to the closed thread located at ["bad words" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515/bad-words-filter), based off the answer that @Unknwntech provided:

```
    public string ReplaceBadWords(string data, string[] badWords, out int badWordCount)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Regex r;
        string op = data;
        foreach (var word in badWords)
        {
            var expword = ExpandBadWordToIncludeIntentionalMisspellings(word);
            r = new Regex(@"(?<Pre>\s+)(?<Word>" + expword + @")(?<Post>\s+|\!\?|\.)");
            var matches = r.Matches(data);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                string pre = match.Groups["Pre"].Value;
                string post = match.Groups["Post"].Value;
                string output = pre + new string('*', word.Length) + post;
                op = op.Replace(match.Value, output);
                count++;
            }
        }
        badWordCount = count;
        return op;
    }

    public string ExpandBadWordToIncludeIntentionalMisspellings(string word)
    {
        var chars = word
            .ToCharArray();

        var op = "[" + string.Join("][", chars) + "]";

        return op   
            .Replace("[a]", "[a A @]")
            .Replace("[b]", "[b B I3 l3 i3]")
            .Replace("[c]", "(?:[c C \\(]|[k K])")
            .Replace("[d]", "[d D]")
            .Replace("[e]", "[e E 3]")
            .Replace("[f]", "(?:[f F]|[ph pH Ph PH])")
            .Replace("[g]", "[g G 6]")
            .Replace("[h]", "[h H]")
            .Replace("[i]", "[i I l ! 1]")
            .Replace("[j]", "[j J]")
            .Replace("[k]", "(?:[c C \\(]|[k K])")
            .Replace("[l]", "[l L 1 ! i]")
            .Replace("[m]", "[m M]")
            .Replace("[n]", "[n N]")
            .Replace("[o]", "[o O 0]")
            .Replace("[p]", "[p P]")
            .Replace("[q]", "[q Q 9]")
            .Replace("[r]", "[r R]")
            .Replace("[s]", "[s S $ 5]")
            .Replace("[t]", "[t T 7]")
            .Replace("[u]", "[u U v V]")
            .Replace("[v]", "[v V u U]")
            .Replace("[w]", "[w W vv VV]")
            .Replace("[x]", "[x X]")
            .Replace("[y]", "[y Y]")
            .Replace("[z]", "[z Z 2]")
            ;
    }
```

This does a fairly good job at preventing clbuttic mistakes (yes, google it) as long as you have a good bad word list.